# How do I write a bash shell script to go through a series of files and pull a column of data out?

Tags: bash, shell, csv

I have a folder of about 10 thousand files and I need to write a bash shell script that will pull a COLUMN of data out and put it in a file. Help??? Please and thank you!

EDIT To Include:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /Users/Larry/Desktop/TestFolder

find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d
sed '4q;d'
```

A separate attempt

```
for dir in /Users/Larry/Desktop/TestFolder
do
  dir=${dir%*/}
  sed -n '4q;d' > Success.txt
done
```

The files are comma separated value files that open in a spreadsheet program like Numbers or Excel in a spreadsheet. I want to extract a single column from each file but there are at least 10 thousand files in each folder so arguments give to error "too long".

Another attempt

`find /Users/Larry/Desktop/modified -type f -maxdepth 1 -name '.csv' -print0 | xargs -0 awk -F '","' {print $2}' find /Users/Larry/Desktop/modified -type f -maxdepth 1 -name '.csv' -print0 | xargs -0 awk -F '"*,*' '{print $2}' > DidItWorkThisTime.csv`

The link to a previous question does not work for large sets of files.

Comment: Use `cut` or `awk`, depending on how the columns are delimited.

Comment: Lol if I had come up with anything useful I would have posted it. My codes (multiple attempts, and those from a friend) flat out haven't worked.

Comment: If you had code that worked, you wouldn't need to ask a question. Post what you tried, and we'll help you get it working. Either that, or hire a programmer who knows what he's doing.

Comment: You're not using the files as input to `sed` in either script.

Comment: I don't understand, sed isn't supposed to be in the script at all?

Comment: Where are you selecting a column out of the file? `4q;d` prints the 4th line, not a column.

Comment: I don't know how to grab a column and not a line?

Comment: What I mean is it should be `sed 'commands' filename` or `somecommand | sed 'commands'` -- it reads the data from a named file or piped input.

Comment: How are the columns delimited? Space, TAB, multiple spaces? Can you show some sample input?

Comment: They are comma separated value .csv files.

Comment: "CELLS","SUM","1 1","ALLCELLS","0.0","number of cells at beginning of month","cfb60ca21c30bb2a7b728a478a02849b.csv" is what it looks like in a text editor; in Numbers (I'm on Mac) it's a regular  spreadsheet of values.

Comment: That's more complicated, you really should have said that in the question.

Comment: How do I do it over a folder of multiple files?

Comment: Give a wildcard filename argument to `awk`, it will process all the files.

Comment: A wildcard filename argument? How do you do that? I was going to put the directory in place of "Textfile.csv" but I don't think that will work?

Comment: `/Users/Larry/Desktop/TestFolder/*.csv`

Comment: Do you know the basics of using Unix/Linux? Wildcards are pretty beginner stuff, not even related to programming, just using the shell interactively.

Comment: Larry$ awk -F "\"*,\"*" '{print $2}' /Users/Larry/Desktop/modified/*.csv > DidItWork.csv
-bash: /usr/bin/awk: Argument list too long

Comment: @user3736201: please edit the extra information into the question, especially where it information like the data format. It is hard to determine the actual layout in a comment.  Generally, add information to the question, not in comments, even though you're adding the information to address a question in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

If the directory has so many files that you exceed the argument limit, you should use `find` and `xargs`.

```
find /Users/Larry/Desktop/modified -type f -maxdepth 1 -name '*.csv' -print0 | 
    xargs -0 awk -F '"*,"*' '{print $2}' > Success.txt
```

Comment: It's definitely a step in the right direction but when I enter the command in the shell and hit enter nothing happens. I also tried to put it in a shell script to run, but it didn't do anything there either? The > is to have the found columns go somewhere I can view the values.

find /Users/Larry/Desktop/modified -type f -maxdepth 1 -name '.csv' -print0 | xargs -0 awk -F '","' {print $2}' find /Users/Larry/Desktop/modified -type f -maxdepth 1 -name '.csv' -print0 | xargs -0 awk -F '","' '{print $2}' > DidItWorkThisTime.csv

Comment: `'.csv'` should be `'*.csv'`.

Comment: If that's what you actually typed, you need to put code inside backticks in comments. Otherwise, `*` is used to make italic and bold words.

Comment: It would be best to add an update to your question, showing what you tried. Then you can format it nicely using the `{}` tool in the SO editor.

Comment: Did so above, see edit

Comment: Did you really put multiple commands on the same line like that? That won't work.

Comment: You're missing all the `*` characters in your command.

Comment: I don't really want to spend hours trying to teach you how to execute basic shell commands. You need to learn how to use the shell or hire someone who knows.

Comment: I feel like if it was basic the programmer in charge could have done it (he could not) and it would be a simple command (clearly it isn't)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
find /Users/Larry/Desktop/TestFolder -type f -maxdepth 1 -name '*.csv' -exec awk -F, '{ print $2 }' '{}' \; > Success.txt
```

It should execute `awk` on each csv file found, using a comma to separate fields (`-F,`), to print the second (`$2`) field, and redirect the output to Success.txt.

Also, you might swap `> Success.txt` for `| tee Success.txt` if you want to see the output AND have it saved to the file, at least while you're testing the command and don't want to wait for all those files to be processed to see if it worked.

Comment: omfg it did something. Stranger, I love you. It says I can't vote up but I would if I would. Infinite vote ups!

Answer (score 0):

A simple and straightforward adaptation of the code you already have.

```
find /Users/Larry/Desktop/TestFolder -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -name '*.csv' |
xargs cut -f2
```

If you want files, `-type d` is wrong.  I changed that to `-type f` and added the `-name` option to select only `*.csv` files.

```
for dir in /Users/Larry/Desktop/TestFolder/*
do
  cut -f2 "$dir"/*.csv
done
```

This is assuming `TestFolder` contains a number of directories, and each of them contains one or more `*.csv` files.  This can be further simplified to

```
cut -f2 /Users/Larry/Desktop/TestFolder/*/*.csv
```

but this could get you the `Argument lenght exceeded` error you tried to avoid.

All of these will print to standard out; add `>Success.txt` at the end to redirect to a file.

Answer (score 0):

`cut -d',' -f1,2,3 *.csv > result.csv`
Assuming the field delimiter in your files is `,` [a csv file after all] and that you need in the result columns 1,2 and 3.

Above command will have problems if needed columns are having the delimiter in the column itself: `"...,...",`